# Is the following a number field?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Is the field obtained by adjoining all the cube roots of $-3$ to $\mathbb Q$ a number field ?

The cube roots of $-3$ are: $-\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{3}e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}, \sqrt[3]{3}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}}$

so is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{3}e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}, \sqrt[3]{3}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}})$ a number field ?

being a number field means being a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ and having characteristic $0$, here it looks like a finite extension (the degrre should be at most $27$), but is there a possibility to have a nonzero characteristic ?

Comment: If $K/L$ is any extension of fields, then $K$ and $L$ must have the same characteristic.

Comment: @JanLadislavDussek Oh, you are a famous [composer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Ladislav_Dussek) !

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\;w\;$ is a cube root of $\;-3\;$ iff $\;w^3=-3\iff w^3+3=0\iff w\;$ is a root of $\;p(x)=x^3+3\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , and thus your field is $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{-3},w)\;$, which is even a Galois extension.

Comment: Thanks.  Can this be generalized: adjoining n-th root of -n to $\mathbb Q$ is always a number field ? Did you take another definition, do you make use of irreducibility of $x^3+3$ ? (Sorry Galois is saying nothing to me)

Comment: Well, reducibility of that polynomial over the rationals follows at once from Eisenstein's Criterion, say. Also, if you adjoin all the $\;n$-th roots of some number you get a finite extension of the basis field.

Comment: So you use: A number field may also be described as $\mathbb Q[X]/(f)$, where $f\in\mathbb Q[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial ?

Comment: Well, yes...yet in the present case I didn't even use a quotient ring *directly*

Comment: Wait, how are you concluding this extension is Galois? The minimal polynomial for $w$ is degree $3$, but the only Galois extensions of $\Bbb Q$ with cyclic Galois group are totally real and clearly not all choices of $w$ are real.

Comment: @AdamHughes You're right: I was thinking of $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{-3},\,w)\;$ in a related problem. Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a number field $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Since obviously $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow K$, it follows that $K$ has characteristic zero. A *function field* is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$, where we have characteristic $p>0$. This plays a parallel role in algebraic number theory to number fields. Together both are called [global fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_field).

Answer (score 0):

Being an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to being a field of characteristic $0$.